# How to make multi-lined, underlined UITextView/UITextField?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

I'd like a multi-line text entry field with the appearance of lined paper, where each entry line has an underline beneath where the text would go spanning the width of the view.

For example:
[image: example image]

This is the design I want to make. The number of lines could change.

I considered:

- Using UITextView and placing a lined background.
- Using TextField and underlining each textField.

None of these sound sane to me, so I'm looking for other ideas that could get me pointed in the right direction.

Comment: What about Tableview?

Comment: Yeah it sounds like a tableview might be the way to go. Do you want the user to be able to directly edit the text?

Comment: @Amanpreet this is a cell of one UItableview.

Comment: @BenjaminLowry not directly in any line. From top to bottom.

Comment: Ah yes, then a tableview will not work.

Comment: you can put uitextfields like this with only bottom border. and disable all other textfield except first. when user press return key or text in textfield reaches to end of field than only enable next textfield.

Comment: @KAR I thought about this idea, but in case, the user deletes some text from and middle textfield, it will be hard to manage all below textfield.

Comment: you might want to check when the texview's text changed and based on the number of its lines, add a view behind each line...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can draw the lines using CoreGraphics:

```
class UnderlinedTextView: UITextView {
  var lineHeight: CGFloat = 13.8

  override var font: UIFont? {
    didSet {
      if let newFont = font {
        lineHeight = newFont.lineHeight
      }
    }
  }

  override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
    let ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()
    ctx?.setStrokeColor(UIColor.black.cgColor)
    let numberOfLines = Int(rect.height / lineHeight)
    let topInset = textContainerInset.top

    for i in 1...numberOfLines {
      let y = topInset + CGFloat(i) * lineHeight

      let line = CGMutablePath()
      line.move(to: CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: y))
      line.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: rect.width, y: y))
      ctx?.addPath(line)
    }

    ctx?.strokePath()

    super.draw(rect)
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks mate. Will defiantly try this.

Comment: To set the proper color, in this example white, after line : let ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext() insert:  ctx?.setStrokeColor(UIColor.white.cgColor).

Comment: Note: this code doesn't scroll lines so it should be modified to get the correct behavior.

Comment: @AndreaLeganza Did you managed to update the code for scrolling support?

Comment: @AkhilKC no sorry, I didn't have the time to code and fix it, so I took another way.

Comment: @AndreaLeganza do you care to provide your solution?

Answer (score -1):

Add textview delegate , and then use this after confirming to UITextViewDelegate delegate

```
func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
      yourTextView.setNeedsDisplay()
}
```

Comment: This makes no attempt to answer the question.